# Datos inconsistentes al hacer scrapping con puppeteer

Tags: nodejs, scraping, puppeteer

estoy haciendo scrapping simultaneamente a 4 urls , utilizo puppeteer-cluster, en principio me funciona bien cuando utilizo unas variables a modo de prueba sin utilizar post, pero cuando creo un servidor con node y le llegan las variables por post una de las funciones que scrapean una url me da el  siguiente error TimeoutError: waiting for selector `.list_ads_row` failed: timeout 30000 ms exceeded, utilizo headless browser por cada funcion.

```
const http = require('http');
var sc = require('./scraper');
var qs = require('querystring');

const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');
var agente = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.99 Mobile Safari/537.36";
http.createServer((request, response) => {
  const { headers, method, url } = request;
  let body = [];
  request.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  }).on('data', (chunk) => {
    body.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', () => {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

     (async () => {
      try{
          var post = qs.parse(body);
         
     if(post.clave2== 'undefined'){
      post.clave2 = null;
     }
     if(post.clave3== 'undefined'){
      post.clave3 = null;
     }

       const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
          concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
          maxConcurrency: 4,
          puppeteerOptions: {
          headless: true,
          args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
         
          },
               });
     
 

      cluster.queue(sc.data.scrape1(post.clave1,post.clave2,
       post.clave3,post.provincia));
      cluster.queue(sc.data.scrape2(post.clave1,post.clave2
      ,post.clave3,post.latitud,post.longitud));
  
      cluster.queue(sc.data.scrape3(post.clave1,post.clave2
      ,post.clave3,post.provincia));
       
      cluster.queue(sc.data.scrape4(post.clave1,post.clave2
      ,post.clave3));

          await cluster.idle();
          await cluster.close();
          } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
      } 
      })();

      });
      }).listen(3000, "***.***.***.***");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas veces, al hacer WebScrapping a webs dinámicas, cuando se obtiene un dato, es posible que en ese mismo instante sí exista, pero medio segundo después no.

Si tu problema viene con webs dinámicas, existen herramientas como puppeteer que te hacen una "captura" de la página web en el instante i y, con la herramienta cheerio puedes convertir esa captura en html y hacer el scrapping sobre ello.

Para más información, te dejo una página web donde tienes más información (está en inglés).
[Quora - Cómo hacer Web Scrapping sobre páginas dinámiscas](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-scrape-content-from-dynamic-web-pages)

Comment: Gracias por la aportación, lo probare